# Is matrix $A^i A^j = A^j A^i$

Tags: matrices

I want to know if $$A^i  A^j = A^j  A^i$$ holds or not. 
It seems like an obvious, but I am wondering if there is a more formal proof

Comment: Does $A^i$ simply mean $\underbrace{A \cdot \ldots \cdot A}_{i \text{-times}}$?

Comment: it is the outcome of associativity of square matrix multiplication

Comment: This is true because of associative property of matrix multiplication. Assuming that your notation means as Stefan wrote

Comment: Yes, that was what I meant

Comment: Also remember not to bogged down by math notation. If you write out both you $A^jA^i$ and $A^iA^j$ you'll see they are same thing. Seek to understand and not just remember identities and such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is pretty trivial, but it follows from the definition of $A^n$ as the product of a string of $n$ copies of $A$.

On one hand, $A^iA^j$ is a string of $i$ copies of $A$, followed by a string of $j$ copies of $A$.  The result is $i+j$ copies of $A$.  That is,
$$
    A^i A^j = A^{i+j}
$$
On the other hand, $A^jA^i$ is the product of a string of $j$ copies of $A$, followed by a string of $i$ copies of $A$.  The result is $j+i$ copies of $A$.  That is,
$$
    A^j A^i = A^{j+i}
$$
Since $i+j = j+i$, we know $A^i A^j = A^j A^i$.